# python dictionary is overwriting itself in a for loop which should not be possible

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary, random

I am having trouble understanding why the python function does not output a dictionary with the appended shuffled lists but instead creates a dictionary of only the last list created. I have rewritten the function many times but continue to run into the same problem.

```
#simple schedule fitness test run
#imports
from itertools import permutations
import random
import numpy as np

#create teachers with classes and students with classes
brian_classes = ['akstuddies', 'sci_ms', 'sci_ms', 'physics', 'comp_sci', 'conf']
becky_classes = ['akstuddies', 'lit_ms', 'lit_ms', 'lit', 'conf', 'debate']
teachers = [brian_classes, becky_classes]
#creates inital population of n schedules by shuffling the schedule of each teacher n times
def initial_population(teachers_list, population_size):
    schudule_list_population = {}
    for i in range(0, population_size):
        shuffled_teachers = []
        schudule_list_population[i] = [teacher for teacher in teachers_list]
        for teacher in schudule_list_population[i]:
            np.random.shuffle(teacher)
            shuffled_teachers.append(teacher)
            #print(teacher)
        schudule_list_population[i] = shuffled_teachers
        print(schudule_list_population)
    return schudule_list_population

print(initial_population(teachers, 2))

output:

{0: [['akstuddies', 'conf', 'physics', 'sci_ms', 'sci_ms', 'comp_sci'], ['lit_ms', 'lit', 'conf', 'debate', 'lit_ms', 'akstuddies']]}

{0: [['sci_ms', 'physics', 'comp_sci', 'akstuddies', 'sci_ms', 'conf'], ['conf', 'lit_ms', 'lit_ms', 'akstuddies', 'debate', 'lit']], 1: [['sci_ms', 'physics', 'comp_sci', 'akstuddies', 'sci_ms', 'conf'], ['conf', 'lit_ms', 'lit_ms', 'akstuddies', 'debate', 'lit']]}

{0: [['sci_ms', 'physics', 'comp_sci', 'akstuddies', 'sci_ms', 'conf'], ['conf', 'lit_ms', 'lit_ms', 'akstuddies', 'debate', 'lit']], 1: [['sci_ms', 'physics', 'comp_sci', 'akstuddies', 'sci_ms', 'conf'], ['conf', 'lit_ms', 'lit_ms', 'akstuddies', 'debate', 'lit']]}
```

Comment: how should your expected output look like?

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding. If you add the same mutable object in multiple places you will just have multiple references to that one object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting python to do a deep copy for you but by default it doesn't so you are storing the same list multiple times.  Here is a simple example

```
In [1]: sub_list = [1,2,3,4]

In [2]: outer_list=[]

In [3]: outer_list.append(sub_list) # doesn't do a deep copy

In [4]: outer_list.append(sub_list) # doesn't do a deep copy

In [5]: outer_list
Out[5]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

In [6]: sub_list[0] = 10

In [7]: outer_list
Out[7]: [[10, 2, 3, 4], [10, 2, 3, 4]]
```

See how there is really only one list? If you want a deepcopy you can do

```
import copy
outer_list.append(copy.deepcopy(sub_list))
```

Your shuffled teachers list is just getting added to your dictionary several times like I added it to my list here.